# How to add more than one variable to an sql

Tags: sql

I have been working on this and I understand the declare statements, but I don't understand it when there needs to be more than 2 declare statments. I am supposed to Update the discounts table to store #7896 where the type is initial customer, set the value of one variable equal to the amount of the maximum discount in the discount table. I named this variable `highDiscount`. Set the value of the next variable equal to the store name that has the highest discount (found in step 2 above). I named this variable `storeName`. Multiply the maximum discount by 10% and put the result into the third variable. I named this variable `discountAmount`. Add the result from `discountamount` to the current max discount and assign the value to the fourth variable. I named this variable `totalNewDiscount`.

This is what I have:

```
Use pubs  
UPDATE dbo.discounts  
Set Stor_Id = '#7896'  

Declare @highDiscount money;  
Set @highDiscount = (Select MAX(discounts) From [dbo].discounts);  
Select @highDiscounts;  

Declare @ storeName money;  
Set @storeName =(SELECT Max(discounttype)FROM dbo.discounts)  

Declare @discountAmount money;  
Set @discountAmount = @discountAmount * 10%
```

At the time this is what I have and am trying to figure out how to add the result from the discount amount to the current max discount and assign the value to the forth variable. I know i could do something like `SET @TotalNewDiscount = @discountAmount + @highDiscount.` But to me I think I have declared too many variables. Now am I able to have all the variables together but are they doing what they are suppose to do?

Answer (score 1):

The code doesn't make much sense. You set `@highDiscount` to be the result of a query, then `select @highDiscounts` immediately afterwards. Typo with the extra `s`?

You also declare `@discountAmount`, but don't give it a value. You then multiply this uninitialized (so it defaults to NULL) variable by `10%`, which is not a valid statement. Null times anything results in null.

To do a 10% calculation, it should be

```
set @discountAmount = @discountAmount * 0.1;
```

and should have a value assigned to it beforehand, so there's actually something to give a discount to.

Comment: I dont know what the discounts are to this.

Answer (score 0):

Watch out the UPDATE, you didn't put any clause, so actually that statement will update EVERY row with "#7896".
Watch out also for the second query, you have too many SELECT. (oh, and there's a typo in trhe variable declaration)

Look carefully at the third query, as I understand you have to select the store name with the highest discount, but you don't use the variable @highDiscount just found above. Again you are missing a WHERE clause.

In the fourth one you use @discountAmount, which is not assigned. As above, you have to use @highDiscounts in that query, to calculate @discountAmount.

Answer (score 0):

Ok you can improve your query a little bit by just doing one select since you are using the same table.

```
Use pubs 

UPDATE 
    dbo.discounts 
Set 
    Stor_Id = '#7896' 
WHERE
  ??????????? -- This needs something to specify which row you want updates

Declare @highDiscount money; 
Declare @storeName money; 
Declare @discountAmount money; 

SELECT 
    @highDiscount = MAX(discounts), 
    @storeName = Max(discounttype)
FROM 
    dbo.discounts
```

Now this wont work

```
Declare @discountAmount money;    
Set @discountAmount = @discountAmount * 10%
```

This is because you have declared it, but not put anything into it. The syntax is also wrong, you need to multiply by 0.10 as Marc B said.

One question though, what are you doing with these variables once you have populated them?

Answer (score 0):

I am working on the same problem and after much research I was able to get it to work, not sure if it is correct but I didn't get any errors and the result is what the instructor was looking for. So, here it is . . .

```
UPDATE dbo.discounts
SET stor_id = '7896'
WHERE discounttype = 'initial customer'
GO

DECLARE @highDiscount money;
SET @highDiscount = (SELECT MAX(discount) FROM dbo.discounts);

DECLARE @storeName varchar(40);
SELECT @storeName = stor_name
FROM dbo.stores st
INNER JOIN dbo.discounts di
ON st.stor_id = di.stor_id
WHERE discount = @highDiscount;


DECLARE @discountAmount money;
SET @discountAmount = @highDiscount * .10

DECLARE @totalNewDiscount money;
SET @totalNewDiscount = @discountAmount + @highDiscount

SELECT @storeName 'Store Name',
       @highDiscount 'High Discount', 
   @discountAmount 'Discount Amount', 
   @totalNewDiscount 'Total New Discount'
```

If anyone wants to give me tips on cleaning it up I would appreciate that.